# function call for pong game made in python throwing AttributeError error

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to create pong using python. i've created various parts of the code and have gotten the ball to appear and move. when i create a wall function to detect collision with the upper and lower bounds of the window i get keep getting an error.

---

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

class Ball(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ball = Turtle(shape="circle")
        self.ball.color("white")
        self.ball.penup()
        self.ball.setheading(random.randint(1, 360))

    def collide(self):
        current_heading = self.ball.heading()
        self.ball.setheading(180 - current_heading)

    def wall(self):
        if self.ball.ycor() == 350 or self.ball.ycor() == -350:
            self.ball.collide()
        else:
            pass

    def move(self):
        self.ball.forward(5)
        self.ball.wall()
```

---

```
from gamescreen import GameScreen
from player import Player
import time
from ball import Ball

screen = GameScreen()
screen = screen.screen
player_1 = Player()
player_2 = Player()
player_1.left()
player_2.right()
player_1.show()
player_2.show()
ball = Ball()

screen.onkeypress(fun = player_1.up, key='w')
screen.onkeypress(fun = player_1.down, key='s')
screen.onkeypress(fun = player_2.up, key='Up')
screen.onkeypress(fun = player_2.down, key='Down')

on = True
while on:
    ball.move()

screen.exitonclick()
```

---

AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'wall'

not sure what i'm doing wrong with regards to class inheritance and making and calling new functions. thanks.

Comment: You define `self.ball` with `self.ball = Turtle(shape="circle")`. So `self.ball` is an instance of `Turtle` and `self.ball.wall()` doesn't make sense. Did you mean `self.wall()`?

Comment: thanks for looking. i've removed self.ball and changed it to just self now. self.wall now does not throw the error, but the actual collision doesn't happen; it just continues off the screen. i would have thought my move function would go 5 steps forward and then the wall function would run and then those two would repeat?